# Proving that the ring is not an euclidean domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider the ring $R= \mathbb Z [(1+\sqrt-19)/2]$.
How do I prove it is not an euclidean domain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a fairly messy (at least as far as I know) proof. The most elementary proof I have seen can be found [here](http://www.uwlax.edu/faculty/LeDocq/mth%20412/pid%20not%20ed.pdf)

Comment: +1 I just spent the last 10 minutes reading the proof in the link. I really like this proof; there is clearly a conceptual idea of considering elements of small norm (which is important for our understanding of a Euclidean domain because the Euclidean algorithm tells us that elements of small norm have nice divisibility properties). Moreover, this conceptual idea is converted into a straightforward proof whose details only involve manipulations with complex numbers.

Comment: @alex youcis : The link which you have attached is no more accessible now.. If you have saved a copy of that or if you have any other link please post it here...  Thank You:)

Comment: Here is a link to a file of the same name, I'm not sure it's the same one: http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~raw/MTH5100/PIDnotED.pdf